# Required Field Validator in ASP.NET not catching Inital Value in DropDownList when set in Codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started populating my DropDownList's items from a table in my database. Ever since I removed the hard-coded items and started using the auto-populated items my RequiredFieldValidator doesn't seem to notice that the InitalValue is still selected when I press submit.

I'm placing the initial value "Select Genre" after I pull the items from the table.

**Here is my DropDownList and my Validator:**

```
<strong>Genre:</strong>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGenres" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvGenres" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlGenres" InitialValue="Select Genre" ErrorMessage="You must pick a genre." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Here is the code from my code behind I'm using to populate the DropDownList:**

```
//Code Outside of my method
static string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

private void populateddlGenres()
    {

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmdGenre = new SqlCommand();
            cmdGenre.CommandText = "Select * From Genre";
            cmdGenre.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Load(cmdGenre.ExecuteReader());
            conn.Close();

            ddlGenres.DataSource = dt;
            ddlGenres.DataTextField = "GenreText";
            ddlGenres.DataValueField = "GenreValue";
            ddlGenres.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        ddlGenres.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Genre", "0"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the textfield on the InitialValue.

InitialValue="0" will solve it